# Basic question on Array and Objects

Tags: javascript

```
var data = [row,row2];
```

This is an Array containing two objects. Can i place some thing like this.

```
var data = [rowData,row2];
```

Where `rowData is an Array containing Objects`. How can i make rowData behave like an Object like rowData[0],rowData[1] etc etc... with in the `data Array`.

Comment: wow you ask alot of questions, but dont contribute much answers to the community at large :-p

Comment: @Neal - Since when was answering questions on SO a requirement? There is no answer/question minimum ratio.

Comment: @Oded, i never said there was :-P

Comment: @Neal - You certainly implied as much.

Comment: @oded, i was just making a statement, calm doooown lol

Comment: if i can answer, then i would... i myself learning things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you mean:

```
var data = [rowData,row2];
//access rowdata:
data[0][1]...
```

or you can use a json object:

```
var data = {
     rowData: rowData,
     row2: row2
};
//access rowData:
data.rowData[1]...
```

Comment: Can you help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669070/accessing-objects-within-objects

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, technically that's not a *JSON* object. It's just a regular old JavaScript object. :)

Comment: @Drackir, then what is a JSON object?

Comment: Well, the JSON equivalent would be: `{ "rowData": "value of rowData", "row2": "value of row2" }` [JSON](http://www.json.org/) has strict rules as to how it is defined (ie. everything in double quotes unless it's an array, object, number, boolean value or `null`). I believe it's safe to say that every JSON object is a JavaScript object, but not every JavaScript object is a JSON object. Take for example, if you had `{"myfunc":function() { /*...*/ }}` This is not JSON, since `myfunc` is a function and has no way to be defined through JSON. However, it *is* a valid JavaScript object.

Comment: Just wanted to add that this is a common misconception; one that I made myself until someone pointed it out to me. :)

Comment: @Drackir hmmm odd. i did not know that

Comment: Actually, after looking at it again, `"value of xxx"` in my comment would actually be an array, but I think you get the idea. Just have a look at the diagrams on the [JSON homepage](http://www.json.org/) and you'll see what I meant about it being very specific.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, arrays can contain arrays.