# Accessing objects within objects

Tags: javascript

```
var data = {
     row: row,
     row2: row2
};

var tableData = [data.row,data.row2];
```

row objects contains lot of children objects too... now how would i placed my tableData to access each single objects. so it goes like this...

```
var tableData = [data.row[1],data.row[2],data.row[3],,data.row2];
```

**Updated Question**

```
var data = [row, row2];
```

In this case how would i access my row children objects.

Comment: you asked that second part already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668833/basic-question-on-array-and-objects/5668863#5668863

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = {key: value, ... };

var tableData = [];
for (var k in data) {
    for (var i = 0, len = data[k].length; i < len; i++)) {
        tableData.push(data[k][i]);
    }
}
```

Use nested for loops and [array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

**Edit**

```
for (var j = 0, len = data.length;j < len;j++) {
    for (var i = 0, len = data[j].length; i < len; i++)) {
        tableData.push(data[j][i]);
    }
}
```

You can replace `for (var j in data)` with `for (var j = 0, len = data.length; j < len; j++)`

The latter

- sets j to 0
- caches the length so you only ask for the length once.
- Checks that j is not bigger then the amount of elements in your array
- Increases j when you get to the end of the block.

Comment: One question what if my data is not an Json Object and instead its an Array of Object like this var data = [row, row2];

Comment: @TheJava then it still works. As long as each row is also an `Array`. You may want to convert the `for in` loop into normal `for` loop.

Comment: @theJava how lazy are you? it's a simple change. Take your hands out of your pocket.

Comment: if i had know i would have not asked

Answer (score 1):

Assign data.row first, then push data.row2, like this:

```
var tableData = data.row
tableData.push(data.row2)
```

Comment: That's the same as `var tableData = [data.row,data.row2];` he already got that far.

Comment: Not the same, assuming `row1 = [a,b,c]; row2 = [d]` his produces `[[a, b, c], d]` and mine produces `[a, b, c, d]` which I think is what he is after.

Comment: true that would work. But only in a very specific case, that does not scale beyond his trivial example.

Comment: @Raynos I am only trying to answer his question here - answers to other questions can found on other question's pages. The example given may not be trivial to @theJava.

Comment: I meant he gave an example of his data rather then the actual data.The actual data probably has more elements.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this...

```
var data = {
    letters : ["a", "b", "c"],
    numbers : ["0", "1", "2", "3"]
};

data.letters; // ["a", "b", "c"]
data.letters[0]; // "a"
data.numbers; // "0", "1", "2", "3"]
data.numbers[2]; // "2"
```

... or you could try this...

```
var data = {
    letters : new Array("a", "b", "c"),
    numbers : new Array("0", "1", "2", "3")
};

data.letters; // ["a", "b", "c"]
data.letters[0]; // "a"
data.letters.push("d"); // the array is now ["a", "b", "c"]

data.numbers; // ["0", "1", "2", "3"]
data.numbers[2]; // "2"
data.numbers.pop(); // the array is now ["0", "1", "2"]
```

For more info on JavaScript arrays, check out these links:

- http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays
- http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/

I hope this helps.
Hristo